# docker-compose file vs docker bundle

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bundle, docker-swarm

This question has been asked before but I am not sure if at that time docker stack deployment could be done using a docker-compose file.
Since recent versions support deployment of services to a stack using compose, if that is the case, I fail to understand the value of a `dab` file.

I checked the `dab` file created out of compose and the structure in `JSON` resembles the `yml` services setup in compose.

So, is `dab` dead or are there some redeeming features that compose cannot provide?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the value of the DAB (Distributed Application Bundle) file?

According to the following [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26876) on GitHub about the **"docker stack deploy" roadmap**, a DAB file represents a portable bundle format for multi-image applications across different Swarm environments.

As you said:

> *"the dab file created out of compose and the structure in json resembles the yml services setup in compose"*

and in addition to the application bundle file you will need to attach a specific configuration file per Swarm enviroment during the deployment. In this way you will get the separation of concerns:

- the bundle file will be the core and static content;
- the configuration file will be the content that changes frequently, 
  let's assume, for example, config, secret objects and etc.

Referencing the official Docker documentation, [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/bundles/), this feature is still experimental. It seems to be a nice idea and it will help to evict writing long and parametrized stack files which result hard to maintain.

As one of the maintainers of [Moby project](https://github.com/moby/moby) said, in the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30352), the default behaviour for "**docker stack deploy**" should be the bundle name.